# Simple memory efficient templating using Python

Tags: python, templates, web-applications

I have a standard HTML Layout that is going to rendered way too many times in Zope Framework and efficiency is a concern . Is it fine to use Python's inbuilt Template as

```
TEMPLATE = 
"""

     <doctype html>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style type="text/css">
     <div id="header"> $header  </div>
     <div id="footer"> $footer  </div>
     <div id="body">   $content </div>

"""
```

Now do `from string import Template` and the usual Template as explained in Python docs

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings

Can anyone suggest a really more memory effeicient way of doing this ? I would even like to avoid file opening for this purpose as this will be done say 1000 times for example in 5 minutes.

PS  : I saw a good resource here https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating... but I am looking for a memory effecient way .

Comment: For me, the best looks like template='''<div..>%s</div>''' then passing % var. For simple template should be fine and fast, with string in memory but w/o IO reading

Comment: It's a bit big becuase I need to specify some margins too a few specs related to paged media .... though simple and standard template ... the thing is it can make the code a bit messy to see , but I think memory advantages should outweigh .

Comment: Use {} named vars to keep things clean (it's hard to count %s)

Comment: Mako, Jinja, cheetah and genshi seemed to be used heavily within the community, some of them offer compilation like steps to improve performance.

Comment: How do you know that doing it the way you have now is not efficient? The point being, this seems like a case of premature optimization because you haven't actually done any benchmark and "1000 times in 5 minutes" is not a solid start of requirements.

Comment: Good question about current memory consumption. We already have dtml in Zope but I really want to use something Pythonic as much as possible

Comment: So what's unpythonic about dtml? What is the _problem you are facing_ that you are looking to solve by replacing the templating component? If you can help define the problem, then others can help with a solution that meets your requirements. Otherwise as it stands your question is very open ended and broad and subject to closure.

Comment: I mean inbuilt python ways for the sake of code portability , suppose I want to publish the code for others they might need to install dtml engines no ?